# Azure Cosmos Db Group By with Select statement

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Our Cosmos Db Container for Doctors is partitioned by networkId. Each Doctor document has id, providerKey, providerFullName, sourceProviderNumber, subType, gender (and few other fields) and then there is an array of offices the doctor is working for that networkId.

I want to write a query to gather all distinct officeIds under all networkId partitions for a single doctor (by sourceProviderNumber).

I am trying something like this:

```sql
SELECT c.providerKey, c.providerFullName, c.sourceProviderNumber, c.subType, c.gender, c.networkId, 
ARRAY(SELECT VALUE providerAddress.officeId FROM providerAddress IN c.providerAddresses) AS offices  
FROM c WHERE c.subType = 'Practitioner' AND c.sourceProviderNumber = '3116'
```

I am getting following response:

```
[
    {
        "providerKey": "1087136",
        "providerFullName": "Cao, Jerry, OD",
        "sourceProviderNumber": "3116",
        "subType": "Practitioner",
        "gender": "Male",
        "networkId": "0000010000010001400005",
        "offices": [
            "5819108595843",
            "820691372145"
        ]
    },
    {
        "providerKey": "1087136",
        "providerFullName": "Cao, Jerry, OD",
        "sourceProviderNumber": "3116",
        "subType": "Practitioner",
        "gender": "Male",
        "networkId": "0000010000010001400002",
        "offices": [
            "5819108595843",
            "113757091145",
            "820691372145"
        ]
    },
    {
        "providerKey": "1087136",
        "providerFullName": "Cao, Jerry, OD",
        "sourceProviderNumber": "3116",
        "subType": "Practitioner",
        "gender": "Male",
        "networkId": "0000010000010001400003",
        "offices": [
            "5819108595843",
            "113757091145",
            "820691372145"
        ]
    },
    {
        "providerKey": "1087136",
        "providerFullName": "Cao, Jerry, OD",
        "sourceProviderNumber": "3116",
        "subType": "Practitioner",
        "gender": "Male",
        "networkId": "0000010000010001400006",
        "offices": [
            "5819108595843",
            "820691372145"
        ]
    }
]
```

I am selecting networkId just to show you how it is used for partitioning. In main query, we can omit it.

I want to write a query somehow to get something like this:

```
[
    {
        "providerKey": "1087136",
        "providerFullName": "Cao, Jerry, OD",
        "sourceProviderNumber": "3116",
        "subType": "Practitioner",
        "gender": "Male",
        "offices": [
            "5819108595843",
            "113757091145",
            "820691372145"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please edit to show an example of the output you're trying to achieve, along with the specific issue(s) you're having with your query (what does it currently output?).

Comment: The `GROUP BY` is only suited if you want to aggregate the data which you don't want. You could separate it into two queries. One to retrieve the data of the doctor and another to retrieve the offices. Then map the data in your backend to a suitable format.

Comment: @DavidMakogon  I have modified the post for accurate example of my query, output and what I want to achieve.

Comment: @NotFound I have modified the post for accurate example of my query, output and what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

**Data stored in my cosmos container:**
[image]

**I tried with the below query:**

```
SELECT c.fullName, c.providerType, c.gender, c.npi,
ARRAY(SELECT  VALUE office.officeName FROM office IN c.offices) AS officeNames,
ARRAY(SELECT  VALUE office.address  FROM office IN c.offices) AS addresses
FROM c
WHERE c.npi =  'Hyderabad'
```

- To retrieve the officeName values for each office in the c.offices array,
  `ARRAY(SELECT  VALUE office.officeName FROM office IN c.offices) AS officeNames`
  this portion of the query employs an array subquery. It creates an array called officeNames that contains all of the office names.
- `ARRAY(SELECT VALUE office.address FROM office IN c.offices) AS addresses`
  This section of the query generates an array called addresses that contains all of the offices addresses.

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: I have modified the post for accurate example of my query, output and what I want to achieve.